# Add parameter to connect in Python

Tags: pyqgis, python-3

I have a plugin in QGIS 3.4.

I have connected `layer.selectionChanged.connect(self.AfterSelection)` and I call the selected layer to know which feature is selected, but when I use the 'Clear Selection' button all the layer are clear but I don't know which layer is modified, so I want to add a parameter to the `connect` to give him the layer.

I tried `layer.selectionChanged.connect(lambda: self.AfterSelection(layer))` but I lose the old parameters
and I don't know how to keep the old and add the new.

Answer (score 5):

You can pass variables for old parameters in lambda function.

```
def AfterSelection(selected, deselected, clearAndSelect, lyr):
    
    # method body


layer.selectionChanged.connect(lambda a, b, c: self.AfterSelection(a, b, c, layer))
```

Comment: Hello i got a strange issu,
I use a function to load some layer and i connect legendLayersAdded
and in the function i connect a lot of event of the layer but for some raison 
the first time I add layer only the connect without lambda connect 
if I use another time the function to load other layer the lambda are connecter 
il i delete and connect again the layer (same function) the lambda work 
do you have a idea of the source of the issue ?

Comment: This is a comment area. Please avoid asking additional questions here. Instead, use [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)" button.